# How does a Model's _eventPrefix get set by extending classes?

Tags: event-observer

`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` contains a field, `_eventPrefix`, which is used to dispatch events.  For example, `_afterSave()` uses it like this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
```

However, in looking for usages in PHPStorm it doesn't look like it's being explicitly written.  How does this value get set--is it by configuration, convention, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::$_eventPrefix` property is a perfect example of how extendable Magento really is. In order to prove this point, let us look into the definition of `_beforeSave()` action which is defined inside the model class `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    if (!$this->getId()) {
        $this->isObjectNew(true);
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_before', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

There are two `Mage::dispatchEvent` call inside this function. This function is used to trigger events, so that we can observe them and make customization or change the default flow of Magento's inner logic.

Every model entity which is defined by any module is an extended version of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. That means every entities in Magento application is a child class of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. With that said, if we look into the events which are dispatching inside the above method, we can see that the first event which is dispatching is **too broad** in nature (`model_save_before`). Since every model entity is extending from `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` class, hence this means this method will be triggered every time when a save action is taking place in Magento application. So this is a perfect event where we can do some general customization. Means customization or change in logic flow which need to affect in almost all modules in magento.

So here comes another question. What about if we need to customize or change the logic flow only for one module or two? Observing a too broad event is not scalabale at all. This is where the second dispatching event or the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::$_eventPrefix` come into action. Every Magento Model entity expected to change this property so that, every model should have a unique event corresponding to deal with that model. An example is shown below.

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix     = 'catalog_category';
}
```

Here you can see that, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` is extending from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` and it changes the value of of its parent property to `catalog_category`. This creates a unique event for category entity which is `catalog_category_model_save_before`. Due to this, we can observe to this unique event and hence make changes in category entity only. This is why Magento is said to be highly extendable in nature.

Hope that will give you an idea.

Comment: Ah, the salient point is that the classes extending `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` are setting it by re-declaring the field, `protected $_eventPrefix = 'catalog_category';`, I'd been looking for it to be set within a constructor via `$this->_eventPrefix = 'catalog_category'`

Comment: Actually it is `catalog_category_save_before` and not `catalog_category_model_save_before`. The `model_` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This value can be overridden by modules.

Modules who do so have a more specific manner of handling events than those who do not.

For example, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product does override _eventPrefix to `catalog_product` and thereby having the `catalog_product_after_save` events which can easily be observed.

For your convenience I've grabbed them for you in `app/code/core/Mage`:
`grep -R _eventPrefix | grep protected | sed -se 's/^.*= /    /' -se 's/;$//' | grep -ve "''" | sort| uniq`

```
'adminhtml_system_config_backend_cookie'
'admin_roles'
'admin_user'
'api_user'
'catalog_category'
'catalog_category_collection'
'catalog_compare_item'
'catalog_entity_attribute'
'cataloginventory_stock_item'
'catalog_product'
'catalog_product_import'
'catalogrule_rule'
'catalogsearch_query'
'cms_page'
'core_abstract'
'core_config_backend_design_exception'
'core_config_data'
'core_file_storage'
'core_file_storage_database'
'core_file_storage_directory_database'
'core_file_storage_file'
'customer'
'customer_address'
'customer_entity_attribute'
'customer_group'
'eav_entity_attribute'
'eav_entity_attribute_set'
'eav_form_element'
'eav_form_fieldset'
'eav_form_type'
'newsletter_subscriber'
'paypal_payment_transaction'
'process_collection'
'review'
'sales_creditmemo_item'
'sales_invoice_item'
'sales_order'
'sales_order_address'
'sales_order_address_collection'
'sales_order_address_resource'
'sales_order_collection'
'sales_order_creditmemo'
'sales_order_creditmemo_collection'
'sales_order_creditmemo_comment_collection'
'sales_order_creditmemo_comment_resource'
'sales_order_creditmemo_grid_collection'
'sales_order_creditmemo_item_collection'
'sales_order_creditmemo_item_resource'
'sales_order_creditmemo_resource'
'sales_order_grid_collection'
'sales_order_invoice'
'sales_order_invoice_collection'
'sales_order_invoice_comment_collection'
'sales_order_invoice_comment_resource'
'sales_order_invoice_grid_collection'
'sales_order_invoice_item_collection'
'sales_order_invoice_item_resource'
'sales_order_invoice_resource'
'sales_order_item'
'sales_order_item_collection'
'sales_order_item_resource'
'sales_order_payment'
'sales_order_payment_collection'
'sales_order_payment_resource'
'sales_order_payment_transaction'
'sales_order_resource'
'sales_order_shipment'
'sales_order_shipment_collection'
'sales_order_shipment_comment_collection'
'sales_order_shipment_comment_resource'
'sales_order_shipment_grid_collection'
'sales_order_shipment_item_collection'
'sales_order_shipment_item_resource'
'sales_order_shipment_resource'
'sales_order_shipment_track'
'sales_order_shipment_track_collection'
'sales_order_shipment_track_resource'
'sales_order_status_history'
'sales_order_status_history_collection'
'sales_order_status_history_resource'
'sales_quote'
'sales_quote_address'
'sales_quote_address_collection'
'sales_quote_item'
'sales_quote_payment'
'sales_recurring_profile_collection'
'sales_resource'
'salesrule_rule'
'sales_shipment_item'
'store'
'store_group'
'system_config_price_scope'
'tag'
'website'
'widget_widget_instance'
'wishlist'
'wishlist_item'
```

Comment: That's useful--although a pain to find.  Is there any reason why a model shouldn't set `_eventPrefix`?  I'm thinking I'll add it as a rule to our coding guidelines and style-checker.

Comment: If it doesn't want to be observed :p You should know that rewrites shouldn't override these values because it could potentially break other things. But for new and clean models I would add it for sake of usage

Comment: Well, the events fire either way--without setting the prefix you just see them as `core_abstract_...` and it takes more work on the observing end to work with them.  But good point about not changing them when extending an existing, non-abstract, model.

Comment: Yes, I found myself already by observing classes and watching for `intance_of` because lack of a _eventPrefix and not want to rewrite a whole object